# Pod doesn't start (not Available and ReplicaFailure)

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-pod

Pod doesn't start. Pod is not shown by  `oc(kubectl) get pods` command.

Error summary:

Type       :      Status : Reason

Progressing    :  True   : NewReplicaSetAvailable

Available       : False :  MinimumReplicasUnavailable

ReplicaFailure :  True  :  FailedCreate

Deployment YAML file:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '2'
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/awag-project/deployments/integrated-repository-webapp
  resourceVersion: '3460356'
  name: integrated-repository-webapp
 
 ...

status:
  observedGeneration: 10
  unavailableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'True'
       ...
      reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
      message: >-
        ReplicaSet "integrated-repository-webapp-d69879c5f" has successfully
        progressed.
    - type: Available
      status: 'False'
      ...
      reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
      message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
    - type: ReplicaFailure
      status: 'True'
      ...
      reason: FailedCreate
      message: >-
        pods "integrated-repository-webapp-d69879c5f-" is forbidden: unable to
        validate against any security context constraint:
        [spec.containers[0].securityContext.containers[0].hostPort: Invalid
        value: 80: Host ports are not allowed to be used
        spec.containers[0].securityContext.containers[0].hostPort: Invalid
        value: 443: Host ports are not allowed to be used]
```

Describe deployment command message:

```
Name:                   integrated-repository-webapp
Namespace:              awag-project
CreationTimestamp:      Tue, 13 Jul 2021 00:31:31 +0900
Labels:                 <none>
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 2
Selector:               app=integrated-repository-webapp
Replicas:               1 desired | 0 updated | 0 total | 0 available | 1 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=integrated-repository-webapp
  Containers:
   integrated-repository-webapp:
    Image:       jp.icr.io/etp-namespace/integrated-repository
    Ports:       9080/TCP, 9443/TCP
    Host Ports:  80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Environment Variables from:
      integrated-repository-webapp-config  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    Environment:
   ...
    Mounts:                                              <none>
  Volumes:                                               <none>
Conditions:
  Type             Status  Reason
  ----             ------  ------
  Progressing      True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
  Available        False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  ReplicaFailure   True    FailedCreate
OldReplicaSets:    <none>
NewReplicaSet:     integrated-repository-webapp-d69879c5f (0/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age                From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----               ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  63m                deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set integrated-repository-webapp-f9cd69684 to 2
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  63m                deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set integrated-repository-webapp-f9cd69684 to 1
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  51m (x3 over 66m)  deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set integrated-repository-webapp-f9cd69684 to 1
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  17m (x3 over 53m)  deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set integrated-repository-webapp-f9cd69684 to 0
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  17m                deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set integrated-repository-webapp-d69879c5f to 0
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  17m (x2 over 18m)  deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set integrated-repository-webapp-d69879c5f to 1
```

---

Edited 1

To start pod by root user  I created a ServiceAccount and attached to deployment.
Pod changed to pending status but not running.
Port error seems to be resolved but it is not Available due to  MinimumReplicasUnavailable.

1.Error Reproduction:

Create Service Account "ir-sa"

oc create sa ir-sa

oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged-z ir-sa

patch to deployment

```
spec:
template:
  spec:
    serviceAccountName: ir-sa
```

2.Deployment YAML file:

```
conditions:
   - type: Progressing
     status: 'True'
     ...
     reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
     message: >-
       ReplicaSet "integrated-repository-webapp-76c767549" has successfully
       progressed.
   - type: Available
     status: 'False'
     ...
     reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
     message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
```

3.describe pod command output

```
 Type     Reason                  Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------                  ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled               5m46s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned awag-project/integrated-repository-webapp-76c767549-rrbcx to 10.244.0.11
  Normal   AddedInterface          5m46s                  multus             Add eth0 [172.17.20.41/32]
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  5m45s                  kubelet            Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to add hostport mapping for sandbox k8s_integrated-repository-webapp-76c767549-rrbcx_awag-project_07f11210-f70e-4553-b598-862b101eb57a_0(61bf202c0bd3423444ec64e8f50a9a1aa2cdf173fe9a638e31a3113ec8775eed): cannot open hostport 443 for pod k8s_integrated-repository-webapp-76c767549-rrbcx_awag-project_07f11210-f70e-4553-b598-862b101eb57a_0_: listen tcp4 :443: bind: address already in use
  Normal   AddedInterface          5m44s                  multus             Add eth0 [172.17.20.56/32]
…

  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  44s (x141 over 5m27s)  kubelet            (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to add hostport mapping for sandbox k8s_integrated-repository-webapp-76c767549-rrbcx_awag-project_07f11210-f70e-4553-b598-862b101eb57a_0(d47342c920507c8e9c65c3afd808caec4f73524d5c08b76ab2dc0db0b1004453): cannot open hostport 443 for pod k8s_integrated-repository-webapp-76c767549-rrbcx_awag-project_07f11210-f70e-4553-b598-862b101eb57a_0_: listen tcp4 :443: bind: address already in use
```

---

Edited 2

I added Ingress and changed deployment's port to 444.
Pod is still pending status but the reason changed to ImagePullBackOff.

**1.Create Ingress**

kubectl get ingress command output
(acutual ingeress-subdomain is edited to INGRESS-SUBDOMAIN)

```
NAME                                   CLASS    HOSTS                                                                                              ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
integrated-repository-webapp-ingress   <none>   INGRESS-SUBDOMAIN            80, 443   24h
```

**2.Change deployment’s port 443 to 444**

Deployent YAML(spec.template.spec.ports)

```
   ports:
            - hostPort: 80
              containerPort: 9080
              protocol: TCP
            - hostPort: 444←(it was 443 before)
              containerPort: 9443
              protocol: TCP
```

**3.got different  error message**

deployment YAML file

```
status:
  observedGeneration: 28
  replicas: 2
  updatedReplicas: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 2
  conditions:
    - type: Available
      status: 'False'
      …
      reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
      message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'False'
       …
      reason: ProgressDeadlineExceeded
      message: >-
        ReplicaSet "integrated-repository-webapp-5bcb99db9d" has timed out
        progressing.
```

describe pod command out put

```
Name:         integrated-repository-webapp-5bcb99db9d-s76br
Namespace:    awag-project
…
Status:       Pending
…
Containers:
  integrated-repository-webapp:
   …
    Ports:          9080/TCP, 9443/TCP
    Host Ports:     80/TCP, 444/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment Variables from:
      integrated-repository-webapp-config  ConfigMap  Optional: false
    …
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  ir-sa-token-v848t:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  ir-sa-token-v848t
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------          ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled       41m                    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned awag-project/integrated-repository-webapp-5bcb99db9d-s76br to 10.244.0.12
  Normal   AddedInterface  41m                    multus             Add eth0 [172.17.54.125/32]
  Normal   Pulling         40m (x4 over 41m)      kubelet            Pulling image "jp.icr.io/etp-namespace/integrated-repository"
  Warning  Failed          40m (x4 over 41m)      kubelet            Failed to pull image "jp.icr.io/etp-namespace/integrated-repository": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unable to retrieve auth token: invalid username/password: unauthorized: The login credentials are not valid, or your IBM Cloud account is not active.
  Warning  Failed          40m (x4 over 41m)      kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed          6m49s (x153 over 41m)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff         105s (x175 over 41m)   kubelet            Back-off pulling image "jp.icr.io/etp-namespace/integrated-repository"
```

Comment: Does that https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/11271  similar to your situation? What's defined in security context constraints?

Comment: I've checked that page before question and attached anyuid ServiceAccount to the deployment but it did not work. Do you know how to create a SCC that allows host port access?

Comment: I think that answer by @bodo is correct, You're running pod by non-root user and trrying to bind ports below 1024

Comment: Pod status changed to Pending status.I added to the question (below "edited").

Comment: Look at the message: 443: bind: address already in use. The host port you are trying to use is already taken by something else on the node. I'd check what is using it and / or change the port. If you need to expose a web-app on port 80 and 443, you could use an Ingress instead of going for host ports. (It requires a bit more setup and an Ingress controller tho)

Comment: I added Ingress and changed port 443 to 444 but pod is still pending due to ImagePullBackOff.I added to the question (below "edited2").

Comment: I resolved by changing ImagePullSecrets settings.I answered by myself.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   message: >-
>     pods "integrated-repository-webapp-d69879c5f-" is forbidden: unable to
>     validate against any security context constraint:
>     [spec.containers[0].securityContext.containers[0].hostPort: Invalid
>     value: 80: Host ports are not allowed to be used
>     spec.containers[0].securityContext.containers[0].hostPort: Invalid
>     value: 443: Host ports are not allowed to be used]
> ```

You are trying to bind application in container to ports 80 and 443 which are < 1024 and that is not allowed for non-root user, what is exactly happend in your case. As in previous issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/68328710/1025312 user [SYN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5607207/syn) has mentioned Openshift uses Random UIDs. So you need to change port in container to e.g 8080, 8443 or any other greater than 1024.

Comment: Since ports <1023 are not allowed for non-root user as you mentioned ,is it possible to solve this by changing to root user ,instead of changing port grater than 1024?

Comment: @Moe Yes, it must be possible this way too. root user has rights on ports below 1024

Comment: To change to root user ,is it correct to change deployment's spec.conatiners.securityContext?

Comment: Pod status changed to Pending status.I added to the question (below "edited").

Answer (score 0):

I need  settings of ImagePullSecret .

```
oc get secret all-icr-io -n default -o yaml | sed 's/default/my-project/g' | oc create -n my-project -f -
```

Then enable all-icr-io at ir-sa(ServiceAccount)

```
oc secrets link ir-sa all-icr-io --for=pull -n my-project
```

Then delete ImagePullBackoff status pod.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-registry#copy_imagePullSecret
Step2 ~4